# SQL Server - How can i insert text file into a table without bulk insert

Tags: sql-server, insert-into

I want to insert a text file into table **without** Bulk Insert command.

**What is the script for it?** I cannot find it anywhere.

There is a script for bulk insert, but I need to do a normal insert.

Comment: Why do you not want to use the right tool for the job?

Comment: Well then do a normal insert then? `INSERT INTO yourtable (yourcolumn) VALUES (@valueForColumn)`, what is the question here.

Comment: how i do a normal insert from text file? what is the scrict? what i found is only Bulk Insert

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way i could think is as follows:
File content is as follows:

id, col1,   col2
2,  A,  B
4,  A,  B

```
declare @test table (id int,col1 varchar(10),col2 varchar(10))
declare @inter table (op varchar(50))
insert into @inter
exec xp_cmdshell 'type  E:\Data\readit.txt'

insert into @test
select substring(op,0,charindex(',',op)),
            substring(reverse(op),0,charindex(',',reverse(op))),
            replace(replace(replace(op,substring(op,0,charindex(',',op)),''),substring(reverse(op),0,charindex(',',reverse(op))),''),',','')
             from @inter where op <>(select top 1 op from @inter)

select * from @test
```

The result is:

```
id  col1    col2
2       B           A
4       B           A
```

As you can see its extremely complicated, so you should use bulk insert